# How to set attribute of a dynamic object in ElasticSearch using C# Nest

Tags: c#, dynamic, elasticsearch, mapping, nest

I have a requirement to set the properties name of an object dynamically in Elasticsearch and I have the following sample code which does the job for me in C# using NEST:

```
var x = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, Object>;
x.Add("Name", "TestName");
x.Add("ch_001", 201.56);

IndexRequest<object> request = new IndexRequest<object>(x)
{
  Index = "test-index",
  Type = "SampleRecord",
  Id = "789456132",
};

elasticClient.Index<object>(request);
```

I need to set attributes or mapping of this document dynamically (e.g. "Name" to `FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed`. If I use static class, I can use the property attributes to achieve my goal, However, I do not know how to do this when I use dynamic object?

Comment: Do you know what keys and their value types will be ahead of time? If you do, you can create a mapping for the index. Elasticsearch is not *schemaless*; it will infer the mapping for documents based on the documents it is passed, but usually, you will want more control over the mapping so will want to provide one explicitly.